# Order of cancellation of effects (useEffect) in React

Tags: reactjs

when a component is unmounted, for some reason, the effect is canceled first for the parent component, and then for the child components... (we are talking about useEffect hooks)

It doesn't make sense...

What could be the problem?

The problem is that I have map routes in my child components.. And when routes are unmounted, they try to delete themselves in the map... and the map has already been removed, because the cancellation of the effect for the parent component is called earlier than for the child components (the child components learn about the parent through the context)

https://codesandbox.io/s/ocherednost-otmeny-effektov-g0z0r

See the browser console

I expect:
Child cancel useEffect
Parent cancel useEffect

Comment: The problem is that the effect is canceled first for the parent component, and then for the children. I need the child components to be unmounted first, and then the parent component.

Comment: can you share sample code for reference

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you might stumble upon a warning about updating unmounted components. You could use the following pattern to work around this:

```
useEffect(() => {

    let mounted = true;

    if(mounted){
        updateMyComponent();
    }

    return () => {
         mounted = false;
    }

}, [deps]);
```

When the component unmounts, `mounted` will change to `false` and `updateMyComponent` will not run. Maybe this solves the issue that you have in your child components?

Comment: No, there are no messages. The problem is that the effect is canceled first for the parent component, and then for the children. I need the child components to be unmounted first, and then the parent component.

Comment: But why would you want this behaviour? What's the issue that you're facing? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16728

We guarantee that parent effects are destroyed before the child ones. The reason for this is that parents often tend to depend on some resource created by the child. Such as removing a listener from a DOM node managed imperatively by a child. If the child disposes its resources first, the parent might not be able to properly clean itself up. This is not specific to Hooks — it’s how componentWillUnmount works as well.

We do not make guarantees about sibling order, whether within a component or between siblings. This is because strong guarantees there hinder refactoring. Within a component, you should be able to re-order Hooks—especially, custom ones. Between siblings, it is expected that you can re-order them safely too. It is also common that only one sibling updates or unmounts, so dependencies between siblings cannot be reliable anyway.